# CSS input box doesn't show in IE

Tags: javascript, php, css

I've scoured this site and tried it all.. so now I'm finally just flat out asking.

http://www.freshcafe.com.tw/EN/FreshSelectSimpleO2_1.php

Here's the link to an ordering page that I'm developing.  It works on pretty much every single browser BUT IE.  Currently, whenever you click on any of the + or -'s to change quantity, the quantity of the item should increase in the upper right hand corner, and the subtotal will be automatically calculated on the lower right hand corner of the right bar.

1. Yes, I know I'm using alot of CSS border radius's.. but I'm just hoping that it will just be boxes in IE.
2. I changed the original input[type="number"] in to a class, as suggested by other posts.  Did not help.  I added a little CSS to remove the spin box for aesthetics sakes.

Just hoping someone, anyone can help me trouble shoot this issue, because I'm hitting a brickwall and have tried many things to try to get those numbers to show up.

Thanks all

Comment: Do you know that it is loading the numbers, the numbers are just being loaded behind the image you have loaded in front of it? Like I can press up and down, highlight the box, copy -> paste and the numbers are there like they should be.

Comment: There wasn't an overwritten issue.  When I finally figured it out.. it was the fact that I had used "line-height: 0em;" so that means the numbers were possibly being drawn outside (to the bottom) of the input fields somehow.  Odd.. in any case.. Yay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this questions is: CHECK THE FORMATTING in IE.
In this case, **line-height: 0em;** was drawing the input value outside of the physical viewable range of the input box that was only 30px in height and width.  The numbers themselves were not seperate from the box so they were not being overdrawn by the pictures.  So I simply started to strip ALL formatting to try to get it to show up.  I actually could NOT find nor select the inputs.

Throwing caution towards the wind, as suggested by other posts, I DID also convert **input[type="number"] to input.number** class since it was stated that IE 6 and below doesn't like that syntax.

Before the issue was resolved, I ALSO inserted the meta tag:
**meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"**

As my current testing box has IE8 (the worst of the incompatibles), and its suggested pretty much about everywhere to render as IE7.